# Starting project on a given url when launching Astro dev server

Tags: vite, astrojs

I have a multi-pages app made with Astro. When starting the dev server with `pnpm start` the default config directly opens my project on the root index.html.

How could I update the config or play with some temp redirection (if this exists) so the server opens the project on a given page, for instance `/blog`?

I have been trying using the vite config like https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-open but it doesn't seems to work...

```
export default defineConfig({
  vite: {
    server: {
      open: 'http://localhost:3000/blog', // also tried '/blog' or even true
    },
  },
  // ...
  },
})
```

Thanks